# Ajax Combo box For Show 2 Buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, combobox

How Can I Make an Ajax Combo box, Forexamle `Female` and `Male`, and i want To show a Button for Female and a Button for Male,
This is My Code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
#for-male, #for-female{
display:none;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<form>
<select name="users" id="users">
<option value="">Select a person:</option>
<option value="1">Male</option>
<option value="2">Female</option>
</select>
<button type="submit" id="for-male" styl>Male</button>
<button type="submit" id="for-female">Female</button>
</form> <br>
<div id="txtHint"><b>Person info will be listed here.</b>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you post the javascript you wrote for `showUser` function

Comment: I Copied From w3 Because i Don't Need To Read From Db,Just i Need to Show a Button For Female and Other Button For Male,or A Text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need an ajax call. If all you want to do is determine the button that will show based on the option selected.

```
<body>
    <form>
      <select name="users" id="users">
        <option value="">Select a person:</option>
        <option value="1">Male</option>
        <option value="2">Female</option>
      </select>
      <button type="submit" id="for-male" styl>Male</button>
      <button type="submit" id="for-female">Female</button>
    </form> <br>
    <div id="txtHint"><b>Person info will be listed here.</b>
    </div>
</body>
```

The javascript will look like this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#users').on('change', function() {
    $('#for-male, #for-female').hide()
    var value = $(this).val()
    if(value == "1") {
        $('#for-male').show();
    } else {
        $('#for-female').show();
    }

  });
});
```

and the css will be

```
#for-male, #for-female{
  display:none;
}
```

Essentially what this does is to show a button whenever an option is selected

You can check https://jsfiddle.net/tmwjge9s/1/

Comment: Appriciate it, Thank You